# Use HTML5 to check inputs in quiz style format

Tags: html, forms, input

I am trying to use HTML5 to offer some sort of live quiz on a webpage. I am not interested in submitting or storing the user inputs on a server, I just want to show the user a direct feedback on whether his inputs are correct or not. I want to use pure HTML5 and a purely client based evaluation, without any javascript or server evaluation.

Unfortunately, I am no HTML expert at all. The HTML5 code I have come up with so far is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Exercise</title>
<style>
/*An incorrect input:*/
input:invalid{
 color:red;
}
/*A correct input:*/
input:valid{
 color:green;
}
*/
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
Complete the missing words using information from the following template:
<ol>
 <li> This is a first test.
 <li> This is a second test.
</ol> 
<p>
 <form action="#.ext" method="post" id="myform">
  <ol>
   <li>
    <label for="GM">This</label>
    <input required
        type="text"
        id="GM" name="GM"
        pattern="is">
    <label for="GM1"> a </label>
    <input required
        type="text"
        id="GM1" name="GM1"
        pattern="first">
    <label for="GM2"> test.</label>
   <li>
    <label for="GM3">This is a </label>
    <input required
        type="text"
        id="GM3" name="GM3"
        pattern="second">
    <label> test.</label>
  </ol>
 </form>
 <button form="myform" type="submit">Check and show correct solutions.</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The HTML5 is already capable of checking inputs against a pattern which contains the correct solution and the change the color of the input element from red to green if the solution is correct.

What I have not managed to achieve so far:

- I'd like the checks for all inputs to start only when the button is pressed (but without submitting the inputs to the server, I want to check locally against the patterns.)
- I'd like to see correct solutions in all input fields as soon as the button is clicked, even if they have been empty before (however I cannot use the placeholders for that because they would be visible from the beginning)
- I'd like to change to colors of the forms only after the button is clicked (e.g. red if solution was wrong and green if it was OK)
- In the best case I'd like to additionally add the wrong user input in red and crossed out plus the correct input in green in one input field.

I am fully aware that I am not using those tools the way they are usually intended to be used, since I am not interested in actualy submitting the content of the input fields to the server.

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: You will need to make use of Javascript to handle the scenarios that you have mentioned.

Comment: I'll leave the question there even if it cannot be done. Even a failed attempt might help someone else..